# php non latin to hex function

Tags: php, encoding

I have website that's in win-1251 encoding and it needs to stay that way. But I also need to be able to echo few links that contain non latin, non cyrillic characters like `šžāņūī`...

I need a function that convert this

```
"m&#257;ja un man t&#257; pat&#299;k"
```

to

```
"māja un man tā patīk"
```

and that does not touch html, so if there is `<b>` it needs to stay as `<b>`, not `&gt;` or `&lt;`

And please no advices about the encoding and how wrong that is.

Comment: Since Win-1251 cannot represent the character "ā", you can only embed it into the page in the form of the escape sequence `&#257;`. Or am I misunderstanding something...?

Comment: yeah that is my question - how to turn ā itno &#257

Comment: Then your question is backwards. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "<b>Obāchan</b> おばあちゃん";

$str = preg_replace_callback('/./u', function ($matches) {
    $chr = $matches[0];
    if (strlen($chr) > 1) {
        $chr = mb_convert_encoding($chr, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
    }
    return $chr;
}, $str);
```

This expects the original `$str` to be UTF-8 encoded, i.e. your PHP file should be saved in UTF-8. It encodes all non-ASCII compatible code points to HTML entities. Since all HTML special characters are ASCII characters, they remain untouched. The resulting string is pure ASCII. Since the lower Win-1251 code points are ASCII compatible, the resulting string is also a valid Win-1251 string. The above `$str` converts to:

```
<b>Ob&#257;chan</b> &#12362;&#12400;&#12354;&#12385;&#12419;&#12435;
```

Answer (score 0):

The main things you probably don't want to encode are <, > and &. Those are really the only special characters. So how about encoding everything first, and then just decode <, > and & I feel you should be fine.

This is untested:

```
$output = 
  htmlspecialchars_decode(
     htmlentities($input, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'CP-1251')
  );
```

let me know

Comment: i changed cp-1251 to win-1251 because it said it does not know cp-1251 and also it does not do the job:

    PlašДЃ izvД“lД“ -> LCD televizori
    saderinДЃšanas gredzeni JЕ«sukДЃzДЃm

needs to be Plašas izvēles ...
saderināsanas gredzeni

Answer (score 0):

What Evert suggest looks logical to me too! If you insist this is a way to do it if there are only two letters that bother you. For more letters the scrit will not be as effective and needs to change.

```
<?PHP 
    function myConvert($str)
    {
        $chars['&#257;']='ā';
        $chars['&#299;']='ī';
                foreach ($chars as $key => $value)  
                    $output = str_replace($key, $value, $str); 
        echo $str;
    }
    myConvert("m&#257;ja un man t&#257; pat&#299;k");
?>
```

==================edited==============

For many characters maybe this one can help you:

```
<?PHP  
    function myConvert($str)
    {  
        $final=null;  
        $parts = preg_split("/&#[0-9]*;/i", $str);//get all text parts
        preg_match_all("/&#[0-9]*;/i", $str, $delimiters );//get delimiters;   
        $delimiters[0][]='';//make arrays equal size  
        foreach($parts as $key => $value)
            $final.=$value.mb_convert_encoding
            ($delimiters[0][$key], "UTF-8", "HTML-ENTITIES");
        return $final; 
    }  
$fh = fopen("testFile.txt", 'w') ; 
fwrite($fh, myConvert("m&#257;ja un man t&#257; pat&#299;k&#299;")); 
fclose($fh); 
?>
```

The desired output is written in the text file. This code, exactly as it is -not merged in some project- does what it claims to do. Converts codes like `&#257;` to the analogous character they present.

Comment: there are a lot of letters, not sure I want to define them all

Comment: I need to do \&#257 => ā and \&#299; => ī, not the other way around. also when I tried it like this it gave me out string(257).

Comment: Sorry but I cannot give an other answear or come back here, I have been warned and downvoted already. As for my second code, your claim **is not true** at all, and I tested this again, I even wrote the output to a text file to be sure!